# Modify Cursor columns value in android

Tags: android, android-cursor

I have a Cursor returned From a SQLiteDataBase object.

I can use getXXX() to get the content of columns from the cursor, but in my case I want to modify "update" data in the cursor using `setXXX()` method. I know there is no `setXXX()` methods, but there is CursorWindow object that has this feature. However, I can't seem to use it .

Comment: You cannot update a Cursor like this. If you want to update your databse, you need to call the update method from your SQLiteDatabase : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])

Comment: the cursor holds 5000 record , so i update the database and requery ? is that good

Comment: If the 5000 records have the same update, you can make in one request this update and query again. To be faster, you can instanciate your Object from your cursor and for set manually the specific parameter that needs to be update and update your databse. Doing like this, you used the cursor without making another query. With the update, next time that you call your method, you will not have to update database again ...

Comment: what i do i want to modify the cursor so i dont need to requery and in the same time i make an update statement to the database to persist the change so , now you have a full overview –

Answer (score 5):

You can't change the cursor.

What you can do is update your database and then use the `reQuery()` method.

```
// code to update your db
cursor.requery();
```

**EDIT**

Further research show that apparently I am incorrect.  You CAN do what you want, but it's quite a bit of work (and no, I haven't tried it, I just requery my cursor).

I found this (using a Google search) on a forum:

> You can subclass SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory to return, from its
>   newCursor method, a subclass of SQLiteCursor. This factory gets passed
>   to the SQLiteOpenHelper constructor so, when you query it, it will
>   return Cursors of your new SQLiteCursor subclass type. The
>   SQLiteCursor subclass can then expose methods that manage its
>   protected mWindow field, which is a CursorWindow. This object has
>   putXxx methods to manipulate the data.

Comment: does the putXXX methods get commited to database?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorWindow.html) no.  It only puts data into the cursor.  You would have to insert it into the DB separately.  Which is what the OP has stated was his goal in further comments, so this oughta work for him.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot alter values returned by `Cursor`. You either need to update your database, hence changing the values pointed by returned cursor or copy the values you get using getXXX into other variables.

Comment: the cursor holds 5000 record , so i update the database and requery ? is that good

Comment: If you want your changes to be permament you need to update the db. If it is not needed, you can copy the data you get from database into an array and do your alterations on it.

Comment: what i do i want to modify the cursor so i dont need to requery and in the same time i make an update statement to the database to persist the change so , now you have a full overview

Comment: make the update and call requery. The query itself should not be long (unless your query is very complex) since a cursor only pulls the actual data when needed.